# 408 Request timed out Microsoft Speech to Text

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

My .wav file length is just 4 seconds. Even after multiple retries and running it on cloud i am constantly getting following error

```
  * upload completely sent off: 12 out of 12 bytes
  < HTTP/1.1 408 Request timed out (> 14000 ms)
  < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  < Content-Type: text/plain
  < Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  < X-MSEdge-Ref:
```

Has anybody faced this issue?
This is my request

```
  `curl -v "https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?
  scenarios=catsearch&appid=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5&locale=en-  
  US&device.os=wp7&version=3.0&format=json&requestid=1d4b6030-9099-12e0-91e4-
  0800200c9a67&instanceid=1d4b6030-9099-12e0-91e5-0800200c9a68" -H 
  "Authorization: Bearer $1" -H "Content-Type: audio/wav; samplerate=8000" -- 
  data-binary $2`
```

Comment: I got this one working by passing the binary data in "@test.wav" format. But now i am getting this error. Connection #0 to host speech.platform.bing.com left intact
{"version":"3.0","header":{"status":"error","properties":{"requestid":"6048c0fa-86e2-4073-993b-63bff15e10b3","NOSPEECH":"1"}}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. There were couple of issues. One was with the locale, which i changed to en-IN. and then scenarios=ulm. This seems to have done the trick. I was able to detect speech very clearly.

Comment: Did you ever run into an issue where it simply timedout?  I can't get mine to issue *any* sort of response, it just hangs. 

my settings are

https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?version=3.0&requestid=5dd196bb-3401-43ff-b23c-754ca159f93f&appID=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5&format=json&locale=en-IN&device.os=Windows&scenarios=ulm&instanceid=4cf56c5e-2d4b-4580-9092-385d3ea39cd7

With the headers

["Authorization"] =>  "Bearer [token]"
["Content-Type"] => "audio/wav; samplerate=16000"

Comment: Yes many times . I used to 408 Request timedout error. But each time it turned out to be a problem with my request. either with the payload or with the parameters. How are you passing the data? try using curl. Also the wave file needs to be passed in "@test.wav" this format  in Unix based environments. Pass me the url with masked jwt token, i can try ur url with my token

Comment: Same problem here. Are there any more scenarios?

Comment: Sorry. I havent come across anymore scenarios. I moved to google speech to text which was much easier to implement. :) I was evaluating different products in this area.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into a few problems getting it to work.  The following BASH script "bingrec.sh" may help make it more clear; enter your SUBSCRIPTION_KEY & adjust SAMPLERATE etc. as required.  As others have pointed out, locale & scenarios need to be set to supported values, and instance_id and request_id need to be in GUID format. The audio file should be less than 10 seconds long, and have a sampling rate of 8000 or 16000.  Also the curl "--data-binary" parameter requires an "@" in front of the audio filename.

```
#!/bin/bash
#  Usage:  ./bingrec.sh  /path/to/file 
#  Send audio file $1 through Bing speech recognition API.
#
SUBSCRIPTION_KEY=<your-key-here>
LOCALE=en-US
SCENARIOS=ulm
SAMPLERATE=8000
CODEC=audio/pcm

TARGET_FILE=$1
if [ ! -f "$TARGET_FILE" ]; then
  echo Error:  file $TARGET_FILE does not exist!
  exit 1
fi

INSTANCE_ID=`uuidgen`    # random GUID for instance
REQUEST_ID=`uuidgen`     # random GUID for request
APPID=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5   # APPID for Bing Speechrec API, don't change
DEVICE_OS=linux          # arbitraty
FORMAT=json

AUTH_TOKEN=`curl -v -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Content-Length: 0" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ${SUBSCRIPTION_KEY}"`

curl -v -X POST "https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?scenarios=${SCENARIOS}&appid=${APPID}&locale=${LOCALE}&device.os=${DEVICE_OS}&version=3.0&format=${FORMAT}&instanceid=${INSTANCE_ID}&requestid=${REQUEST_ID}" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}" -H "Content-type: audio/wav; codec='${CODEC}'; samplerate=${SAMPLERATE}" --data-binary @${TARGET_FILE}
```