# 403 forbidden error on Curl command

Tags: curl, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I'm running this script:

```
function getuuid() { echo `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-f0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1 |  perl -ne 'print join("-", /(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})/);'`; }
curl -v -X POST "https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?scenarios=smd&appid=......&locale=en-US&device.os=linux&version=3.0&format=js$
```

And I'm getting a 403 error back... I don't know what I'm doing wrong here

Another script I use

```
export SPEECH_TOKEN=`curl "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ................" --data-ascii ""`
function getuuid() { echo `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-f0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1 |  perl -ne 'print join("-", /(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})/);'`; }
curl -v "https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?scenarios=smd&appid=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5&locale=en-US&device.os=your_device_os&version=3.0&format=j$
```

Comment: Did you get an access token first?  Docucumentation is [here](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/oauth-token.html) Cited documentation is for the Translator API but the same applies to other Bing services, including Speech.

Comment: @cthrash Yes I now have another script that generator a access token, but then it gives me a time-out error

Comment: I'm on mobile right now, but you might take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139809/408-request-timed-out-microsoft-speech-to-text.