# Bing Speech API cURL > 408 Request timed out (> 14000 ms)

Tags: php, azure, curl, speech-recognition

I'm trying to build a PHP based app using the Bing Speech API.

Following the example from this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstarted-curl), I tried to adapt it into a PHP request.
Getting the JWT access token was quite simple, and I managed to adapt the raw cURL request into PHP based cURL request.

However getting the audio file recognized is proving to be a headache.
At first I tried several methods of converting the code into PHP based cURL request, none of which works. They all ended up returning "408 Request timed out (> 14000 ms)" error. I thought it had something to do with my PHP script. However further tests with using the example URL (obviously substituting with the proper id's and all), also gave me the same "408 Request timed out (> 14000 ms)" error.

I tried to search around for answers across the web, but no luck. There was this link ([408 Request timed out Microsoft Speech to Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139809/408-request-timed-out-microsoft-speech-to-text)), but that seems to be using an older version of the API, which when I tried only resulted in a "403 Forbidden" error.

The straight cURL I tried was:

> curl -v -X POST "https://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US&locale=en-US&format=detailed&requestid=d8d3c0ed-fca2-4418-b12a-9526ffefa729" -H 'Authorization: Bearer [_token_id_obscured_]' -H 'Content-type: audio/wav; codec="audio/pcm"; samplerate=16000' --data-binary @[_wav_filename_obscured_]

And I've tried with several files, all of them less than 10 second long. The files are exported using Audacity, with project rate set at 16000Hz, file format is "WAV (Microsoft) signed 16bit PCM".

Any input on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this issue you'll also need to add the following request header in the command:

```
-H 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked'
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, that was indeed what was needed. Annoying that the official documentation doesn't say this.

By the way any suggestion on how to improve the accuracy of the detection? So far the accuracy level I'm getting is extremely appalling, not a single file I fed to the API generated anything close to what was said. I've tried changing the locale, but no luck so far, is there any other hidden settings somewhere?